# Zorro package error while compilation after upgrading to Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, ng-zorro-antd

I am facing this error during compilation after upgrading my angular and zorro version.

```
Error: node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/tree-view/toggle.d.ts:10:9 - error TS2611: 'recursive' is defined as a property in class 'CdkTreeNodeToggle<T, T>', but is overridden here in 'NzTreeNodeToggleDirective<T>' as an accessor.

10     get recursive(): boolean;
```

My zorro version
"ng-zorro-antd": "^17.1.0"

My angular versions

```
"@angular/animations": "^17.1.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.1.2",
"@angular/common": "^17.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^17.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^17.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.3",
```

Comment: This issue was already posted as a bug report in their GitHub: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/8364